# Why are CT scans much smaller than the raw data?

Tags: radiation, information, x-rays, imaging

I'm not too familiar with CT, but I worked with medical CT images long ago, and recall that the raw data, recorded by the scanner was way bigger than the 3D image itself (Both were 16-bit TIFF files, I believe)

Is my recollection correct? And if so, why is this the case?

It's my understanding that the processed result (the 3D image) is obtained by solving a system of equations (linear in log space?). Shouldn't we be able to get about as much information out of this process as we put in?

Comment: I think we could use a `tomography` tag, but I don't have enough rep to put it in.

Comment: CT faces a so called "inverse problem". While the mapping of the actual structure to the CT data is fairly simple, the "invers" reconstruction problem is ill-defined. There is no system of linear (or non-linear) equations that can be used to calculate a unique structure from the data.

Comment: If you want to "get about as much information out of this process as we put in", then you would have to wade through all the noise, since most of the raw image data would be coming from where the beams are not even yet passing through the body.

Comment: @FatterMann There isn't a serious inverse problem in CT. The projection theorem allows you to obtain the Fourier transform of the object from the Fourier transforms of its projections.

Answer (score 2):

A single slice from a medical CT is typically a 512x512x2 byte image.  A single CT study can contain anywhere from 10s of images to ~1000-2000 images depending on the scan length, reconstructed slice thickness and slice spacing interval.

The raw data on the other hand, consists of a series of projections at different angles around the patient.  Depending on the detector array in the scanner, each projection consists of several hundred to a few thousand samples.  For a modern CT scanner, there are around 4000 projections acquired for a single rotation.  Scale this by the total length of the scan, scan pitch  (for helical scanners) and you can easily get raw data files in the hundreds of GB.

While the reconstruction problem can be represented as a system of linear equations, this has never been a practical way of doing tomographic image reconstruction.

Comment: Is the Radon transform equivalent to solving a system of linear equations?

Comment: Your answer seems to assume that the scanner's pixel size must equal the voxel size of the 3D image, and that the hundreds of projections are required: *"The sizes and numbers are as follows, and that's why one is bigger than the other"* But they are actually **chosen** by the designers of the hardware and software, or by the user.